# How to specify XTemplate repeat with Ext.NET using Razor syntax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extjs, razor, ext.net

I'm trying to repeat some data with a XTemplate. The template is implemented using Razor with asp.net mvc. For a single data item I can make the template work, but now I want to make it work with multiple items. I looked in the doc and it should be easy using the for="." approach. Only issue is I can't see how to set it using aspnet mvc Razor syntax.

My template is like this

```
.Data(new []{new{menu = "testmenu2"}, new {menu = "testmenu1"} })
.AutoEl(o => {o.Tag = HtmlTextWriterTag.Ul; })
.Tpl(X.XTemplate().Html(@"<li><a href='#'>{menu}</a><li>"))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second time I find the solution short after posting a question :)

Of course I just need to add the for='.' to the template itself like this

```
.Tpl(X.XTemplate().Html(@"<tpl for='.'><li><a href='#'>{menu}</a><li></tpl>"))
```